# My AutoConvert Lead trigger will not deploy in production

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I have create an AutoConvert lead trigger to convert a lead if a specific field gets populated. It works fine in Sandbox, but when I try to deploy it in Production, it fails. I'm driving myself crazy figuring out why there are still 11 failures in test that won't let me deploy!

Here is the trigger I am using:

```
trigger LeadConvert on Lead (after insert,after update) {
//Bulkified
List<String> LeadNames = new List<String>{};
for(Lead myLead: Trigger.new){
 if((myLead.isconverted==false) && (myLead.Trial_Submit_Date__c != NULL)) {
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
        lc.convertedStatus = 'Sales Qualified Lead';
        //Database.ConvertLead(lc,fal);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        }
        }
}
```

And here are the errors I am receiving:

### Apex Test Failures

```
DocuSignRestServiceTest 
test_docusign_addDocuSignSecurityHeader 
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: <DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>e5bc3a7c-4f93-458b-8c30-c8ee30320b71</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>34a53d77470eeeb9918434dd7dbfbb83@unit.test</Username><Password>70b804bdcfcb2c4efb47ff8122dd4d42</Password><IntegratorKey>DOCU-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2a</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials> 
    Stack Trace: (dsfs)

EnvelopeControllerTest  
testSaveContact 
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: ShowError, Actual: ShowSuccess 
    Stack Trace: (dsfs)

TestLicenseChecker  
Test_getCurrentUserLicenseType  
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false 
    Stack Trace: (pw_sifree)
```

Comment: Can you share the failing test classes?

Comment: I've gotten it down to 3 errors now. They are all DocuSign related so I'm not sure what the issue is. It's the following that are still showing up: :
DocuSignRestService
EnvelopeController
LicenseChecker

Comment: We'd have to be able to see those test classes in order to be able to help, assuming those are "local" tests. Otherwise, you may need to contact your vendors for additional assistance; their code definitely should not be crashing during your unit tests.